# How to process an array with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an API returning the following simple JSON array:

```
[
  "efd98ad-first_key",
  "100eb0a-second_key"
]
```

I am trying to render this as a table with Angular:

```
<div name="listkeys" class="container">
  <div class="starter-template">
    <div ng-bind-html="message"></div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed sortable" ng-init="getKeys()">
      <tr>
        <th>bucket</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="bucket in buckets">
        <td>{{bucket}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('flipDaSwitch', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('ListKeys', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.getKeys = function() {
    $http.get('/api/keys').
      success(function (data) {
        $scope.response = data;
      }).
      error(function (data){
        $scope.response = {}
      });
  };

});
```

It does not do anything but throwing an "Uncaught object" error and that is it.

How could I debug why it is failing?

Comment: The answers are right, but `Uncaught Object` is thrown because one of your module dependencies is not met. Are you importing the `angular-sanitize.js` file?

Comment: @Mike thanks for the answer this was the last item before my little homepage started to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the values in `$scope.response`, but you are using `$scope.bucket` at the `ng-repeat`:

```
$scope.getKeys = function() {
$http.get('/api/keys').
  success(function (data) {
    $scope.buckets= data;
  }).
  error(function (data){
    $scope.buckets= {}
  });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have a scope item called `buckets`.   I'd expect to see:

```
$scope.buckets = data
```

Inside the success callback.